# Access to directories and files out of nodejs project

Tags: node.js, iisnode

Is there any way to access some directories or files out of nodejs project?
I have nodejs project running on IIS and I want to create and save some files to c:\myFolder.
But it seems this is from IIS that does not allow to access directories and files out of project.

Comment: Yes of course. Did you have a look at the [fs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html) standard package ?

Comment: Is your problem with permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I think the solution is using fs library. but you have to grant permission in IIS to do that. 
The way that I'm using for this job is changing the identity of pooling in IIS. But be aware of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is: Using the `fs` module.

You can just require that module wherever in your NodeJS project like this

```
const fs = require('fs)
```

Then you could do whatever you want with the file system of your server. (as long as the API of `fs` module support). More details available here [File System API - NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)